# Problem with JPA Annotation @Transient

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to mapping a data base from "Drupal" with Hibernate and JPA to make a Java layer for work with the data.

In a class, I need to add an attribute, called "rank" to use it later, but that attribute doesn't exist in the database, so I put @Transient annotation...

I use the set method to put a value on it, but later, the values are wrong (I don't understand why) So... there is a way to make that without modifying the data base?

Thanks a lot

Edit:

Class contributor

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "biblio_contributor_data")
public class Contributors implements Comparable {
@Id
private int cid;

private String name;

private String firstname;

private String lastname;

private Member memberProfile;

@Trasient
private int rank;
```

Then, I have some Articles, with a list of Contributors as attribute.

And I have a List of Articles. Now I have to update theirs rank, and sort the Contributors list by rank:

```
public static List<Article> sortByRankArticles(EntityManager em, List<Article> list){
for (Article article:list){
        for(Contributors c:article.getAuthors()){


            List<BiblioContributor> result  = em.createQuery("from BiblioContributor where nid = "+article.getId() +" and id.cid = "+c.getCid()).getResultList();

            c.setRank(result.get(0).getId().getRank());
            System.out.println(c.getRank());

        }

        Collections.sort(list);
    }
```

With that system.out... I checked that the values are correct, "0,1,2,3,4,5"

But when I finish the first "for", I made a test in the same method, to prove if the values are ok, but I get the following values: 0,0,1,2,2,3 wich are wrong

```
for (Article article:list){
        System.out.println("///////"+article.getId());
        for(Contributors c:article.getAuthors()){
            System.out.println("***"+c.getRank());

        }
    }
```

Comment: you are doing fine, post some code to see if there are revelant data.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your replies, I'll put my code, I didn't do it before because I'm mapping a data base from drupal and it is weird as hell...

Comment: Can you calculate this with a single select?

Comment: only select? or one single statement?

Comment: in fact, there is one sigle statement: "from BiblioContributor where nid = x +" and id.cid = y

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Formulas` to calculate it directly from the database.

You place the query you would be using to calculate it in you database.

Another way to achieve that is with `Formulas` by placing sql

For a `position` column existing in  this table:

```
@Formula("position + 1")
public int getRank() {
    return this.rank;
}
```

Another way is with `PostLoad` by calculating

```
@PostLoad
public void onPostLoad() {
    int rank;
    // Calculate Rank
    this.rank = rank;
}
```

Note that I do not know your code. So I cannot be more descriptive.

Regards.

Comment: I'm looking for the way to "save" some values in objects witch they don't have that value on a table and without creating a new field on any table

Comment: That is what it does. The attribute rank might be an Object.